# How can I play .3gp audio file in HTML

Tags: html, html5-audio

I am using simple HTML5 audio tag. For `.mp3` file it is working fine. 
But I want to play .3gp file.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Did you get your answer? If yes, why did not accept it? Let other people know that this problem (if) solved

Answer (score 1):

Browsers support only limited audio formats. see

- http://caniuse.com/#search=audio

3GP files are not playable in all browsers. Convert 3GP files to MP3 files, for example using [Audacity audio editor](http://www.audacityteam.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use video tag for video, because `3gp` is a video extension.

```
<source
  src="video.3gp"
  type='video/3gpp; codecs="mp4v.20.8, samr"'>
</source>
```

to [learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) you can read this page on Mozilla.

Comment: Not working .....

 <source src='filename.3gp' type='audio/wav'></source>
        <source src='filename.3gp' type='audio/mpeg'></source>
        <source src='filename.3gp' type='video/3gpp; codecs='mp4v.20.8, samr''></source>

Comment: `<source>` tags do not have a closing tag. Also the quotes are mangled on the `type` and `codecs` attributes' values.

Comment: @zer00ne I think Mozilla is a good Source, I did not write this from myself, Take a look at Mozilla website in link in my answer!

Comment: @Kermani my bad, sorry. I looked at that mangled part of the type/codec and it's correct (never needed to use either one). As for the closing `</source>` tag, where it's under *Error Handling* for Mozilla, yet if you go to the [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) page, it says *"Tag omission ... It must have start tag, but must not have an end tag."*