# how can i play android call recorder 3gpp files in browser

Tags: html

I am using simple HTML5 audio tag. For .mp3 file it is working fine. 
But I want to play android call recorder .3gpp files.

```
<audio controls preload='none' style=' width:200px;'>
<source src='file.3gpp' type='audio/mpeg'>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35433202/1790644).

Comment: 3gp is video format but 3gpp is the android call recorder output 
thanks but this post is not related i already seen it

Answer (score 0):

The point is, **the Browser must support the file type** you provide, not all browsers support all file types and codecs. Usually you have to add alternative source so that all browsers have at least one format that they can support. Just putting audio/mpeg in the type field does not do the trick.

Check this list of supported media formats:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility

You can convert your file to something like a MP3 or OOG using [Audacity audio editor](http://www.audacityteam.org/home/), but there is no change that you just tweak you HTML so that all browser can play your original file (audio/3gpp).

You can add your file in the first line and any browser that supports that format will pick it up, if not than the browser tries the next till he reached the end than he shoes the message "Your browser does not support the audio element."

```
<audio controls preload='none' style=' width:200px;'>
   <source src='file.3gpp' type='audio/3gpp'>
   <source src='file.ogg' type='audio/ogg'>
   <source src='file.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: this files is upload from android device and should run from the browser
is there anyway to convert 3gpp files using php or jquery

Comment: Only because a Device understand a format, dose not mean that a Browser do it as well. I'm not a expert in audio file conversion, but you can start to look here on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428624/convert-audio-files-in-php